# Pandas: write condition to filter in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have dataframe

```
member_id,event_time,event_path,event_duration
19440,"2016-08-09 08:26:48",accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier,0
19440,"2016-08-09 08:27:04",ebesucher.ru/surfbar/Ochotona,25
19440,"2016-08-09 08:27:53",accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier,0
19440,"2016-08-09 08:27:53",accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier,2
19441,"2016-08-09 08:27:55",accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#password,1
19441,"2016-08-09 08:27:58",neobux.com/m/l/,0
19441,"2016-08-09 08:27:59",neobux.com/m/l/,0
19441,"2016-08-09 08:28:01",http://new.enjoysurvey.com/ru/survey/649/index/m_e48f6e46bf0d222e2be70bc9067730c423423,11
19441,"2016-08-09 08:28:12",echo.msk.ru ,1
19441,"2016-08-09 08:28:15",neobux.com/m/l/?vl=A206591715C607425417A51CDE023499,2
```

I need to create new column with `visiting`, and if `new.enjoysurvey.com/ru/survey/649/index/m_e48f6e46bf0d222e2be70bc9067730c4` contain in `event_path` and next `event_path` contain `['echo.msk.ru', 'edimdoma.ru', 'glaz.tv', 'vesti.ru']`, than `visiting == 1`, else - `2`.
If it complete to `member_id`, give to member_id visiting=1
Desire output

```
member_id,event_time,event_path,event_duration, visiting
19440,"2016-08-09 08:26:48",accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier,0,2
19440,"2016-08-09 08:27:04",n,25,2
19440,"2016-08-09 08:27:53",accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier,0,2
19440,"2016-08-09 08:27:53",accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#identifier,2,2
19441,"2016-08-09 08:27:55",accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&passive=true&rm=false&continue=https://mail.google.com/mail/&ss=1&scc=1&ltmpl=default&ltmplcache=2&emr=1&osid=1#password,1,1
19441,"2016-08-09 08:27:58",neobux.com/m/l/,0,1
19441,"2016-08-09 08:27:59",neobux.com/m/l/,0,1
19441,"2016-08-09 08:28:01",http://new.enjoysurvey.com/ru/survey/649/index/m_e48f6e46bf0d222e2be70bc9067730c423423,11,1
19441,"2016-08-09 08:28:12",echo.msk.ru ,1,1
19441,"2016-08-09 08:28:15",neobux.com/m/l/?vl=A206591715C607425417A51CDE023499,2,1
```

I try

```
df['visiting'] = df.groupby("member_id").event_path.transform(lambda g: (g.isin(["new.enjoysurvey.com/ru/survey/649/index/m_e48f6e46bf0d222e2be70bc9067730c4", 'echo.msk.ru', 'edimdoma.ru', 'glaz.tv', 'vesti.ru']).sum() > 1).astype(int)).replace(0, 2)
```

But it determine only size of quantity `event_path`, but I need to consider the sequence. But don't know how to do this.

Comment: Next `event_path`? Do you mean next row? Also, this is not making sense: *If it complete to member_id , give to member_id visiting=1*.

Comment: @Parfait I mean if `event_path` in next string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider a `groupby.apply()` which uses a loop through `event_path` strings. With loop you can search adjacent elements by list indices:

```
def findevent(row):
    event_paths = row['event_path'].tolist()    
    row['visiting'] = 2

    for i in range(len(event_paths)):
        if 'new.enjoysurvey.com/ru/survey/649/index/m_e48f6e46bf0d222e2be70bc9067730c423423' in event_paths[i] and \
                            event_paths[i+1] in ['echo.msk.ru', 'edimdoma.ru', 'glaz.tv', 'vesti.ru']:
            row['visiting'] = 1
            break            
    return(row)

df = df.groupby(['member_id']).apply(findevent)
print(df)

#    member_id           event_time                                         event_path  event_duration  visiting
# 0      19440  2016-08-09 08:26:48  accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&...               0         2
# 1      19440  2016-08-09 08:27:04                      ebesucher.ru/surfbar/Ochotona              25         2
# 2      19440  2016-08-09 08:27:53  accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&...               0         2
# 3      19440  2016-08-09 08:27:53  accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&...               2         2
# 4      19441  2016-08-09 08:27:55  accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=mail&...               1         1
# 5      19441  2016-08-09 08:27:58                                    neobux.com/m/l/               0         1
# 6      19441  2016-08-09 08:27:59                                    neobux.com/m/l/               0         1
# 7      19441  2016-08-09 08:28:01  http://new.enjoysurvey.com/ru/survey/649/index...              11         1
# 8      19441  2016-08-09 08:28:12                                        echo.msk.ru               1         1
# 9      19441  2016-08-09 08:28:15  neobux.com/m/l/?vl=A206591715C607425417A51CDE0...               2         1
```

**NOTE: your first URL search, `new.enjoysurvey.com/...` is not contained in your posted data. Above changes this url to item in data for code demonstration.